# How to use environment variables in my discord bot code

Tags: python, operating-system, environment-variables, discord.py

The code below works correctly however, I want to save the Server ID and Mod ID as environment variables. When I change the command to the following I receive Errors saying "NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_channel'.

```
import discord
import os

@client.event #client event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  print("Recognized that member left")
  guild = client.get_guild(14312441343214)#Server ID
  channel = guild.get_channel(12123134134134)#Mod ID
  await channel.send('Hello '+ member.name + ' has left the server')

#after changes does not work
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  print("Recognized that member left")
  guild = client.get_guild(os.environ.get("SERVERID"))#Server ID
  channel = guild.get_channel(os.environ.get("MODID"))#Mod ID
  await channel.send('Hello '+ member.name + ' has left the server')
```

When I `print(os.environ.get("SERVERID"))` I get the correct value so I'm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are always returned as strings, however IDs in `discord.py` are integers, simply cast them:

```py
    guild = client.get_guild(int(os.environ.get("SERVERID")))  # Server ID
    channel = guild.get_channel(int(os.environ.get("MODID")))  # Mod ID
```